# Chrome ignore history changes when user clicks in back button of the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to include an url in the middle of the history for the button back of the browser goes to this url instead of, for example, an `about:blank` page (first load).

I have this function:

```
function updateHistory(url) {
  const currentURL = window.location.href;
  window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
  window.history.pushState({}, '', currentURL);
}
```

Works perfectly in Firefox and Safari, but in Chrome browser requires that the user clicks at least in an element to do this update.

I tried listening the `popstate` event instead but Chrome doesn't detect anything.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
  window.location.href = url;
});
```

**Does anybody knows about this behaviour in Chrome and knows how can I handle it ?**

Thanks a lot in advance for your time

Comment: see https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7832